# Align text to the bottom of a div with inline-block

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having trouble aligning some text to the bottom of a div which as a display of inline-block.

[image: Right Now it looks like this]

but i can't place the text "BackOffice" in the bottom right corner of the div...

[image: The yellow square marks the spot]

I've tried to use vertical-align. i've used divs, inside of divs, inside of divs, ect., i've tried the table-cell too nothing really works.

Any ideias? (Yes i've read almost every single thread in this website and other forums, nothing really works.

Here's my code.
Thanks!

```css
#firstBox, #secondBox, #thirdBox, #fourthBox, #fifthBox {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

#firstBox {
  background: url(/images/black.jpg);
}

#secondBox {
  background: url(/images/blue.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <!-- Todos os elementos(divs) têm que estar preenchidos para não perder o formato de linha. -->
  <div id="firstBox"><!--
--><div id="firstBox-content>"><a href="backoffice.php">Backoffice</a></div>
  </div><!--
--><div id="secondBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div><!--
--><div id="thirdBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div><!--
--><div id="fourthBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div><!--
--><div id="fifthBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

(The rest of the boxs are the same just except the background change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Flexbox** can do that:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
}
#firstBox,
#secondBox,
#thirdBox,
#fourthBox,
#fifthBox {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="firstBox">
    <div id="firstBox-content>"><a href="backoffice.php">Backoffice</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="secondBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
  <div id="thirdBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
  <div id="fourthBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
  <div id="fifthBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use **CSS Tables**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
#firstBox,
#secondBox,
#thirdBox,
#fourthBox,
#fifthBox {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid green;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="firstBox">
    <!--
        -->
    <div id="firstBox-content>"><a href="backoffice.php">Backoffice</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--
        -->
  <div id="secondBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
  <!--
        -->
  <div id="thirdBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
  <!--
        -->
  <div id="fourthBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
  <!--
        -->
  <div id="fifthBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad somebody suggested **Flexbox**.

Comment: Thanks the flex worked like a charm.

The tables do nothing but i've already found my solution! Cheers Mate!

Comment: Flex wont support IE < 10 versions

Comment: Which is why I gave an alternative option that works back to IE8.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding `position:relative` to the parent element and `position:absolute` to child element with two more properties as shown below

```
#firstBox, #secondBox, #thirdBox, #fourthBox, #fifthBox{position:relative}
#firstBox a, #secondBox a, #thirdBox a, #fourthBox a, #fifthBox a{position:absolute; bottom:5px; right:5px}
```

Or 
By adding below properties to `#firstBox, #secondBox, #thirdBox, #fourthBox, #fifthBox` you can achieve it `display: table-cell;vertical-align:bottom;text-align:right`

Answer (score 0):

I love using "Relative + Absolute" positioning

Try this Code:

```css
#row {
  width: 100%;
}

#firstBox,
#secondBox,
#thirdBox,
#fourthBox,
#fifthBox {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#firstBox {
  background-color: black;
}

#secondBox {
  background-color: blue;
}

#thirdBox {
  background-color: green;
}

#fourthBox {
  background-color: purple;
}

#fifthBox {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="row">
    <div id="firstBox">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="backoffice.php">Backoffice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondBox">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="">Backoffice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="thirdBox">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="">Backoffice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fourthBox">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="">Backoffice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fifthBox">
      <div class="content">
        <a href="">Backoffice</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can't apply Vertical-align into elements
for more information: read This [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, and to directly answer the question as asked, here's how to do it with `display:inline-block;` -

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header > div {
  text-align:right;
}
.header > div::after {
  content: '';
  line-height: 200px;
}

.header > div * {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

#firstBox,
#secondBox,
#thirdBox,
#fourthBox,
#fifthBox {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-right:-4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div id="firstBox">
    <div id="firstBox-content>"><a href="backoffice.php">Backoffice</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="secondBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
  <div id="thirdBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
  <div id="fourthBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
  <div id="fifthBox"><a href="">Backoffice</a>
  </div>
</div>
```